# Failing to run an infinitely running command at startup

Tags: linux, cron, systemd

I want to use gpu-screen-recorder to record replays. I installed it using flatpak and am using the following command to start the replay mode:

```
flatpak run --command=gpu-screen-recorder com.dec05eba.gpu_screen_recorder -w DP-1 -f 60 -o ~/Videos/Captures -c mp4 -r 150 -a alsa_output.usb-BEHRINGER_UMC202HD_192k-00.HiFi__hw_U192k__sink.monitor
```

This process hogs the current terminal.

Since I don't want a blocked terminal window running constantly, and I would like to just have it start on startup, I created a script at `~/scripts/startup/gpu-recorder-flatpak-command.sh` that I want to run at startup. The script is executable and has a shebang. If I just type the filename into the terminal, it works as expected. Meaning, I can send a command (`killall -SIGUSR1 gpu-screen-recorder`) in another terminal and have the past 2.5min of video saved to the specified location.

Now, to get it to start at startup, I tried using cron and I tried creating my own systemd service.

For using cron I tried using `crontab -e` to put `@reboot ~/scripts/startup/gpu-recorder-flatpak-command.sh`
in the cronjob file. I also tried putting `@reboot sleep 10; ~/scripts/startup/gpu-recorder-flatpak-command.sh`, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

When cron didn't work I didn't really check why, I just went to the systemd route. My service file is at `/etc/systemd/system/gpu-screen-replay.service`, which has the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=GPU screen record replay service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=lenny
ExecStart=/home/meekah/scripts/startup/gpu-recorder-flatpak-command.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I did execute `systemctl enable gpu-screen-replay.service` and when running `systemctl` my service gets listed as `loaded active running`.

Do you have any suggestions what I could try or check for error messages? I tried checking `journalctl` but it seemed like it was just starting the service without errors.

Comment: Try adding "&" to the end of the command to background it?

Comment: @davidgo this seems to disable the replay functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like something you should be starting as part of your GUI session, not as system service.

Creating a `*.desktop` file at `~/.config/autostart/` is nowadays the traditional method supported by most graphical environments. The most basic such file would look like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Some app
Exec=~/whatever.sh
```

---

###### More general answer

You need to run the program

1. **at** (or after) **the correct *stage* of startup** – "startup" is a process, not a single instant, and not all system components become available in the same moment; some facilities become available earlier, others later.

   A systemd .service that doesn't have any dependencies listed gets grouped up into "after basic.target but otherwise as early as possible", which may well be too early.

   If your program shows a GUI window through X11 – even if it doesn't use X11 for actual recording – that still means it relies on X11 being started, which is one of the very last things to happen; *much* later than cron "@reboot" jobs are processed. (In fact, X11 is started for you the moment you *log in,* so it doesn't even count as part of the boot process in general.)

   Even if the program doesn't depend on X11, it probably wants to access the GPU via /dev and it could very well be that some system services run before the GPU driver is loaded. (It's unlikely for GPU drivers – those are nowadays loaded *very* early – but that's nevertheless something you need to consider.)

   (And because it's a Flatpak app, it may well rely on various other user-level services that get started only when you log in.)

   So every time you need to auto-start something, you need to think about what its dependencies are and how to specify them (within systemd it would be done using `[Unit] After=` and sometimes `[Unit] Wants=`).
2. **in the correct *environment*** – not all processes run in the same environment; this primarily refers to "environment variables" specifically, but also to environment in the more general sense (i.e. various other parameters).

   Regarding environment variables, your GUI session has a lot more than what a service would have – merely setting `User=` doesn't automatically set them for you. Specifically, for X11 you need `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`; for Wayland you need `WAYLAND_DISPLAY`; for PulseAudio (for the `-a` option) you need `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`; quite a few other things rely on `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`. Those are the typical "bare minimum" for anything GUI-ish.

   There are also other things that might consist "environment", such as login sessions that are used for access control (even a process running under your UID might not be granted the same access if it belongs to a service).

   So for anything that needs access to any "user" GUI component, it is always best to start the program *from within* the GUI environment that's already set up when you log in – that way it'll inherit everything necessary, just like your terminal app does. Almost all desktops support auto-starting programs at login time; the aforementioned `~/.config/autostart/` is the most common method although there are usually a few others.

> Do you have any suggestions what I could try or check for error messages? I tried checking journalctl but it seemed like it was just starting the service without errors.

If journalctl doesn't capture output, try looking at the unfiltered log without the `-u` option; very-short-lived processes may sometimes not get correctly tagged with their corresponding unit name.

Check whether `systemctl restart` gets the service to work. If a manual restart makes it launch, it's almost guaranteed to be some kind of "missing dependency" issue as described earlier.

Use `systemd-run` to create and start a dynamic service from the terminal; this has a small advantage in that you can use `--pipe` or even `--pty` to directly attach the service's output to your terminal (which is otherwise impossible for regular services) while still having the process be launched via systemd. This may reveal error messages that otherwise don't show up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extensive answer! I will take a look after work, but I just wanted to show appreciation already :)

Comment: so it looks like a restart using systemctl did not make it work. I have no idea of all the under the hood stuff so right now, based on your explanation, I assume it might still have to do with services not having access to the environment variables, so i'll try the GUI autostart you mentioned :)

Comment: for anyone else reading this, I needed to add `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true` for it to actually autostart. There seems to be a similar parameter for KDE.